# Recoger miniatura de video de la API de youtube

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Si tengo la URL de un video de Youtube.

¿Cómo puedo acceder a las miniaturas de ese mismo video?

> Publicación en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Respuesta en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068371/4840995

Cada video de Youtube tiene 4 imagenes generadas. Tienen un formato predecible de la siguiente manera:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/0.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/1.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/2.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/3.jpg
```

El primero en la lista será una imagen completa y las otras serán miniaturas.
La miniatura por defecto (ej de: `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`) son:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/default.jpg
```

Para la versión de alta calidad de la miniatura usar:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/hqdefault.jpg
```

También hay una miniatura de mediana calidad utilizando la siguiente URL similar a la de alta definición:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/mqdefault.jpg
```

Para la definición estandar utilizar:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/sddefault.jpg
```

Para la máxima resolución de la miniatura utilizar:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

Todas las URL anteriores estan disponibles en http también. Adicionalmente, el nombre del host acortado `i3.ytimg.com` o `i.ytimg.com` que funciona en el lugar de `img.youtube.com` en los anteriores ejemplos.

De otra forma, también se puede utulizar los datos de la [API de Youtube (v3)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) para recoger las miniaturas:

Comment: Para añadir el host también puede ser  `i.ytimg.com` y también `i9.ytimg.com` anque este último puede ocasionar problemas y mostrar la imagen default de youtube en algunas ocasiones

Comment: @Sr1871 lo actualizo, ¿Ese error a que se debe?

Comment: Me imagino que es del lado de youtube, ya que a veces en el api trae la imagen con el host `i9.ytimg.com` y hay veces en que se ve la imagen gris y otra la original, de hecho en 2 computadoras diferentes se llega a presentar la gris y en la otra la que debe ser, la solución ahí ha sido cambiar el host a `i.ytimg` y funciona bien.